# What is the differences between DHCP Options and Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dhcp

I am a newbie to AWS. I have read about DHCP Option Set and also about Route 53. However, I do not understand clearly about the similarities and differences between them.
In my understand, both help us customize DNS name, and DHCP is a component of VPC, but Route 53 is an AWS service, am I right? If yes, is there any differences between them? In which case we use DHCP? In which case we use Route 53 instead of DHCP Options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route 53 is a DNS service - this allows you to publish hostnames and their associated ip addresses to the world at large. For example, on a simple level, I might publish the following:

www.example.com   A   123.45.67.89

This would tell internet users around the world that the server www.example.com can be found at ip address 123.45.67.89

This is hugely simplfied, but think of Route 53 as a part of a distributed, decentralised database of hostnames and ip addresses.

DHCP is used by a host to get its network configuration at startup. When a machine, or vps, or ec2 instance starts up, it will make a DHCP request for its network configuration, and a dhcp server will respond, giving the host a number of parameters, but at a minimum an IP address. The dhcp *may* then register this ip address/hostname combination in DNS. DHCP options are extra network configuration parameters, for example, telling the host that is part of the domain example.com, that its default router is 10.0.0.2, or any number of other options. These affect the way the host configures itself to talk to the network.

Comment: Yeah! Now I understand! Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

[DHCP in your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html) is used to automatically assign domain names to your EC2 servers that are generated by Amazon. The domain names will look like `ec2-public-ipv4-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Route53 is a DNS service for assigning custom domain names that you own to your AWS resources. If you wanted to assign someting like `myapp.mydomain.com` to your EC2 server, you wouldn't be able to accomplish that with DHCP, you would need to use a DNS service like Route53.